# Changing Date Format depending on the Filter

Tags: tableau-api

So I have a report in Tableau which is a table and has two date columns. I want to make a change: create a field with two values: USA and EU and filter report by it. So if users select USA, date columns on that report should have the format: 3/14/2020 and if users select EU date columns on that report should have the format: 14.3.2020. Is that possible and how can I do that? Or if anyone has some suggestion how to display these two different formats to different users?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with the date being a string, you could create a calculated field that accounts for this. You could use a parameter with the values list of "USA" and "EU".

Then write a calculated field like:

```
IF [parameter] = "USA" THEN STR(MONTH([DATE])) + '/' + STR(DAY([DATE])) + '/' + STR(YEAR([DATE]))
ELSE  STR(DAY([DATE])) + '.' + STR(MONTH([DATE])) + '.' + STR(YEAR([DATE]))
END
```

Other than that, I think Tableau will only allow you to use one Date Format for each column.